# webpack 2.2.1 arranging dependencies in the wrong order / location

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

I have a typescript `.ts` file with the following.
I am using webpack version `2.2.1`

```
import { module } from "angular";
import "typeahead";

class TypeAheadController {
    static $inject = ["$log", "$timeout", "$http", "$interpolate"];
    constructor(
        public $log: ng.ILogService,
        public $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService,
        public $http: ng.IHttpService,
        public $interpolate: ng.IInterpolateService) {

        // do stuff with Typeahead / Bloodhound.
        var bloodhoundSuggestions = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: _ => Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace(_[this.inputValue]),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    }
```

because the typeahead definitions are in `@types/typeahead` and the implementation is in `typeahead.js`, it's necessary to alias the location in `webpack.config.js`

```
globule = require("globule");

var configuration = {
    context: __dirname,
    resolve:
    {
        alias: {
            typeahead: "typeahead.js"
        }
    },
    entry: [
        ...globule.find("client/*.ts", { srcBase: "wwwroot/js/admin" })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: "./wwwroot/js/admin/admin.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    }
};

console.log(configuration);
module.exports = configuration;
```

Unfortunately in the resulting generated javascript file, `Bloodhound` is undefined.

Webpack seems to include and use the relevant require (323), but it's clearly not working as `Bloodhound` is undefined.

in the output file, the require is present just before the controller is defined.

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });    
var angular_1 = __webpack_require__(16);    
__webpack_require__(323);    
/**    
 * initialise and use a type ahead to find suggestions.    
 */    
var TypeAheadController = (function () {
```

much further down the file, I find 323.

```
/***/ }),
/* 323 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(setImmediate) {var __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__;var __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__;/*!
 * typeahead.js 0.11.1
 * https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js
```

**How do I fix the undefined Bloodhound?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package is a quirky one. It is named **typeahead.js**, but the `"main"` entry in package.json actually *exports* the `Bloodhound` function and *attaches* the typeahead function to `jQuery.fn`. To make matters worse, its `@types` package has the wrong name (missing `.js`) and is written using a declaration format that expects you to import from `"bloodhound"`. This is painful but can be worked around.

Here are the steps you need to take:

1. Install **typeahead.js** with npm (since you are using Webpack)

   ```
   npm install --save typeahead.js
   ```
2. install the `@types` package (note no `.js`, this is annoying)

   ```
   npm install --save @types/typeahead
   ```
3. Remove the alias it is not needed. Specifically, the following line must be removed from **webpack.config.js**:

   ```
   typeahead: "typeahead.js"
   ```
4. Create a declaration file **ambience.d.ts** (name is not significant)

   ```
   declare module "typeahead.js" {
       export = Bloodhound;
   }
   ```

   Unfortunately the code above refers to the global `Bloodhound` which the `@types/typeahead` unconditionally declares. Fortunately it will not be global at runtime.
5. Adjust your code so it is roughly as follows

   ```
   import angular from "angular";
   import Bloodhound from "typeahead.js"; // note the `.js`

   class TypeAheadController {
       static $inject = ["$log", "$timeout", "$http", "$interpolate"];
       constructor(
           readonly $log: angular.ILogService,
           readonly $timeout: angular.ITimeoutService,
           readonly $http: angular.IHttpService,
           readonly $interpolate: angular.IInterpolateService) {

           // do stuff with Typeahead / Bloodhound.
           const bloodhoundSuggestions = new Bloodhound({
               datumTokenizer: _ => Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj
                   .whitespace(_[this.inputValue]),
               queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
           });
       }
   }
   ```